# how to make the last line in this table

Tags: equations, vertical-alignment, arrays

please how to make the last row in the table ? I try but it the second column did not be centered

[image]

this is my try

```
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c| } 

 \hline

 R(x) & Form of $y_p$  \\ 

  \hline  \hline

$Cx^n$ &$A_0x^n + A_1x^{n-1} + \ldots + A_{n-1}x + A_n$  \\ 

\hline

$ Ce^{rx}$ & $Ae^{rx}$  \\ 

 \hline

 $Ce^{rx} cos(kx)$\\  $Ce^{rx} sin(kx)$ &$ Ae^{rx} cos(kx) + Be^{rx} sin(kx)$\\

 \hline

\end{tabular}
```

[image]

Comment: please add the tags what you tried...

Comment: It would be great if you could  show us what you have tried. Posting a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that indicates what you are trying to do makes it easier for people to understand what you want. It also makes it easier for people to help you, since they have some code to start from, and hence much more likely that some one will try to help you.

Comment: Unfortunately you've added only a code snippet. This is better than nothing, but still not a minimal *working* example. Please have a look at the link in Andrew's comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use, e.g., an `array` in an `array`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{array}{|c|c|}
    \hline
    R(x) & \text{Form of }y_p \\
    \hline\hline
    Cx^n & A_0x^n+A_yx^{n-1}+\cdots+A_{n-1}x+A_n \\
    \hline
    Ce^{rx} & Ae^{rx} \\
    \hline
    \begin{array}[c]{@{}c@{}}
      Ce^{rx}\cos(kx) \\
      Ce^{rx}\sin(kx) \\
    \end{array} &
                  Ae^{rx}\cos(kx)+Be^{rx}\sin(kx) \\
    \hline
  \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: array in array]

Comment: @MarwanAliSharawy Meanwhile you've several questions with helpful answers. Please note, that you should vote for good answers and that it would help other, if you could accept answers. See our [Help Center](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help) for information [why voting is important](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) and [The Tour](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tour) how to do so.